# Tem como deletar uma pasta dentro de um repositório direto do site do GitHub sem usar Git?

Tags: git, github

Tem como deletar uma pasta dentro de um diretório direto do site do GitHub sem usar Git?

Gostaria de deletar uma pasta, mas não sei se é possível sem o Git.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Entre no arquivo e clique na lixeira conforme marcado abaixo:

[image: Apagar Github]

Em tese isso é o mesmo que um outro cliente Git fazer a remoção e deve manter histórico que uma remoção ocorreu como se tivesse feito pelo Git. Obviamente que se você tem um repositório em outro lugar precisará sincronizar com essa nova versão disponível no GitHub que agora não tem mais esse arquivo.

A pasta só pode ser apagada automaticamente se não tiver arquivos nela. Então apague todos os arquivos e a pasta some automaticamente. Git não mantém pastas vazias sem algum truque.

Fora isso, ou usa o Git ou alguma API. Apagar tudo de uma vez de forma simples não tem como pela web. [As pessoas querem isto](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/225).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado @bigown, e desculpa pela demora, validei sua resposta! ^^